# encrypted mountain lion is not booting , showing osx utilities screen

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

encrypted mountain lion is not booting , showing osx utilities screen . I have two accounts , user1 , user2. User2 is encrypted . Everything was working fine but when I tried to access guest account it showed a dialog saying it needs to restart the machine . Machine restarted but since then it's showing osx screen. Disc is encrypted and isn't getting booted from there.

-- I didn't create any accounts by mistake.
--I turned on file vault for user2 . So usually when turned on my computer , it used to ask password of user2 to unlock / decrypt the hard disk first and then allowed to access other users.

Everything was working fine, but I tried to access guest account for which it demanded restarting.

In osx utilities when I chose startup disk, it shows encrypted disk, when I enter the password, it decrypts the disk.when I accessed /volume/machintosh hd from terminal it showed my all files intact.

So there has to be a way to make it able to boot from it.
Please help

Comment: Do you have recent backups?  Its very likely something critically has gone wrong.  Did you backup your recovery key?

Comment: I didn't . I just know the password of the dis. To unencrypt.

Comment: So you have no backups of your files and didn't backup your recovery key, if thats the case, its very possible you are simply boned.

Comment: If you accidentally created multiple accounts, or want to merge your new account with an old one, please see: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Please explain what you mean by User2 is encrypted? I have just created a user account called User2 and cannot find settings for encryption.  When I checked the Guest User account it says that remote access is not allowed, or if `File Vault` is turned on. Is your `File Vault`on? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you created http://superuser.com/users/264374/gaurang and http://superuser.com/users/199691/gaurang-agrawal which is two accounts.

Comment: That is why you do not have permission to edit this question and also can not write comments here -- the question belongs to the other account.